# How to convert this string into separate string objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, parsing

New to Google Tag Manager and not sure how to do this. On my thankyou page, let's say there is:

```
var purchased =  "product1;product2;product3"
```

How would I separate each string in 'purchased' so that I have something like this (product), so then Tag Manager can understand there are 3 unique strings:

```
   var product = {"product1"}, {"product2"}, {"product3"}
or var product = {"product1", "product2", "product3"}
```

I tried these but it wasn't exactly what I needed:

```
var products = purchased.split(';');
var products = purchased.split(';').map(e => e);
    // both of these return ["product1, product2, product3"]
```

Comment: `purchased.split('; ')`.

Comment: I would encourage you to replace all spaces with an empty space.  Its unreliable to split on text that has spaces.  I would do this
`purchased.replace(new RegExp(' ', 'g'), '').split(';')`

Since you have removed spaces from your purchased string this works just fine `purchased.split(';')`

Comment: Also, `map` is not needed, the result will be an array already

Comment: {"product1"} is a syntax errror...

Comment: Kind of looks like you want to remove duplicates with some sort of set notation? `new Set(purchased.split('; '));`

Comment: Also fix your comment: `// both of these return ["product1", "product2", "product3"]`

Comment: @DougCoburn use `split(';')` rather then `split('; ')`.

Comment: Or if there are quotes **in** the string that you need to remove: `purchased.replace(/"/g,"").split(';').map(a => a.trim())`

Comment: @MrGeek Thanks, you're right.

Comment: {"product1"} is a syntax error as {"product1", "product2", "product3"} @Jonasw is right. You just can not do what you want!

Answer (score 0):

How about splitting by `;(space)`? Your code leaves a space.

```
var products = purchased.split(';');
```